Equivalence form of $L(1,f)\ne0$
In Livingston's 1964 paper "The Series $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{f(n)}{n} $ for Periodic $ f $", it is claimed (without proof) that the following holds:
Let $ f(n) $ be a periodic number-theoretic function with period $ q $. Additionally suppose there is some positive integer $n$ such that $f(n) \ne 0$. Then, the series
$$
S = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{f(n)}{n}
$$
converges to a nonzero number if and only if
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{q} f(n) = 0.
$$
For $ q = 2 $, if we take $ f(n) = (-1)^{n+1} $, then this claim is true. But what about other choices of $ f(n) $? I couldn't even prove this claim for $ q = 2 $. Any helpful hints would be much appreciated.

Have you worked out $\sum _k \frac a{2k}+\frac b{2k+1}$ when $a+b=0$ and $a+b\ne 0$?

@TedShifrin, yes, I assumed both $a+b=0$ and $a+b\ne 0$ to see what happens but I couldn't rearrange the terms to proceed further.

Try a common denominator?

@TedShifrin, yes I did so but if $a+b=0$ then the sum is nonzero. If $a+b \ne 0$, then $b=-a+c$ where $c$ is some nonzero number. I want to manipulate the series but since the absolute sum is not convergent so I can't rearrange the series.

Grouping in consecutive pairs is not rearrangement and does not require absolute convergence.

A comment that got too long - the post above is a bit misleading as actually Livingston shows that if $q > 2$ there are counterexamples with $f$ periodic of period $q$ and the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{f(n)}{n}$ converging to zero (Corollary $2.1$ in the paper)
As for the claim that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{f(n)}{n}$ converges iff $\sum_{n=1}^{q} f(n) = 0$ that is almost trivial.
If $\sum_{n=1}^{q} f(n) = 0$ then the partial sums of $f(n)$ are uniformly bounded and the Abel-Dirichlet criterion (summation by parts) shows that the series converges.
Conversely if $\sum_{n=1}^{q} f(n) = a \ne 0$, then considering $g(1)=f(1)-a, g(k)=f(k), k=2,..q$ extended by periodicity then $\sum g(n)/n$ converges as above and $\sum f(n)/n$ differs from it by an obviously divergent series.
One can find the paper by Livingston HERE

Summation by parts is definitely a very effective tool for problems like this, and it is not limited to a denominator of the given form.
Here is a derivation that does not use summation by parts.
1. Reduction
Let $S_n=\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{f(j)}{j}$. The series converges if and only if the subsequence of partial sums  $(S_{n_k}:k=1,2,,\dots)$, with $n_k= 1+k q, converges. To study the convergence of the latter define
$$ h(s) =\sum_{j=0}^{q-1} \frac{f(j)}{s+j}.$$
Then $S_{n_k}  =\sum_{k=0}^{k-1} h(1+kq)$, and so we need to find necessary and sufficient conditions for the convergence of the series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty h(1+kq)$.
2. Calculations
Observe that
$$ \frac{1}{s+ j} = \frac{s }{s(s+j)} =\frac{(s+j) - j}{s(s+j)} = \frac{1}{s} - \frac{j}{s(j+s)},$$
and therefore
$$ h(s) = \frac{\sum_{j=0}^{q-1} f(j)}{s} - \frac{1}{s^2}\underset{=e(s)}{\underbrace{\sum_{j=0}^{q-1}\frac{f(j)js}{(j+s)}}}.$$
Observe that for all $s>0$, $|e(s)|\le \max_{j=0,\dots,q-1} |f(j)|q^2$.
Putting it all together,
$$ \lim_{k\to\infty} S_{n_k} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty h(1+kq)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{\sum_{j=0}^{q-1} f(j)}{1+kq} - \frac{e(1+kq)}{(1+kq)^2}\right).$$
The boundedness of $e$ and the $p$-test yield the result.
